# Can't see removal flags

Tags: django, django-comments

**Django 3.0.8**

**django-comments-xtd==2.6.2**

I'm studyint this section of the tutorial:

https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#removal-suggestion

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load comments %}
{% load comments_xtd %}

{% block title %}{{ object.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="pb-3">
  <h1 class="text-center">{{ object.title }}</h1>
  <p class="small text-center">{{ object.publish|date:"l, j F Y" }}</p>
</div>
<div>
  {{ object.body|linebreaks }}
</div>
{% get_comment_count for object as comment_count %}
<div class="py-4 text-center">
  <a href="{% url 'blog:post-list' %}">Back to the post list</a>
  &nbsp;&sdot;&nbsp;
  {{ comment_count }} comment{{ comment_count|pluralize }}
  ha{{ comment_count|pluralize:"s,ve" }} been posted.
</div>


{% if object.allow_comments %}
<div class="card card-block mb-5">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title text-center pb-3">Post your comment</h4>
      {% render_comment_form for object %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% if comment_count %}
<ul class="media-list">
  {% render_xtdcomment_tree for object allow_flagging allow_feedback %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
COMMENTS_XTD_APP_MODEL_OPTIONS = {
    'blog.post': {
        'allow_flagging': True,
        'allow_feedback': False,
        'show_feedback': False,
    }
}
```

Full code at Github: https://github.com/Kifsif/comments

**Problem**

I have loged in. But I can't see any flag at the right side of every comment’s header.

Could you give me a hint where the problem may be hiding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to import the font awesome stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```